# Cointegration and variance of time series

Tags: options, volatility, time-series, cointegration

Given that $X_t , Y_t$ are two cointegrated random processes,
what can we say about the relationship between variance of the two increments

$var(X_{t+h}-X_t)$ , $var(Y_{t+h}-Y_t)$ for a given $h>0$?

Thanks

Comment: This should have been posted to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) because it considers statistical properties of time series. You should be able to get the answer there.